# $block is not working in override phtml file

Tags: magento2, overrides, phtml, custom-block

I override totals.phtml, but when I am calling my custom block in it, its not working.

File path:

> Magento/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml

Override File path:

> SimpleMagento/RewardPoint/view/adminhtml/templates/order/totals.phtml

File: sales_order_view.xml

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_totals">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">SimpleMagento_RewardPoint::order/totals.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Override totals.phtml:

```
  /* @var \SimpleMagento\RewardPoint\Block\Sales\Order\ShowReward $block */
 ?>
 <table class="data-table admin__table-secondary order-subtotal-table">
    <td class="label"><strong>Customer's Reward Point:</strong></td>
    <td><?php $getValue = $block->getReward(); ?>
       <strong> <?= $getValue ?></strong>
    </td>
```

$getVaue displays null, however, I when I change in `sales_order_view.xml`

```
  <referenceContainer name="order_additional_info">
        <block class="SimpleMagento\RewardPoint\Block\Sales\Order\ShowReward" name="sales_order_view_custom" template="order/view/custom.phtml" />
  </referenceContainer>
```

File: ShowReward.php

FilePath:

> SimpleMagento\RewardPoint\Block\Sales\Order\ShowReward

```
public function getReward(){
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
    $getOrder = $this->factory->create()->load($id);
    return $getOrder['reward_point'];
}
```

and its displayed value perfectly, but its not showing in `order totals` box, so I override totals.phtml

Comment: post your getReward() function

Comment: @RkRathod I updated the question, As I mentioned block is working perfectly in my other phtml file

Comment: in order object you can directly get the value so you dont want to create this function

Comment: I did not understand, what you are trying to say

Comment: you get the reward point value in order object like this $order->getRewardPoint(); or $order->getData('reward_point')??

Comment: $order->getRewardPoint(); this way

Comment: check in params you get order id or not ??

Comment: as I said block is working perfectly, I am getting value in my phtml file, just read the question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In `totals.phtml` file :-**

```
/* @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Totals $block */

$order = $block->getOrder();
$rewardPoint = $order->getRewardPoint();
```

Comment: its working, :)

Comment: can you please explain me little bit about your answer

Comment: in this file module-sales/Block/Order/Totals.php around line no. 73

Comment: you are find this function getOrder() so simply you can use this function,, :)